# Toggle md-sidenav to a different component

Tags: angular, components, toggle, angular2-template, angular-material2

so this is my main component which contains the header, sidebar and the content

```
<md-sidenav-container>

  <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  <app-header></app-header>


  <div class="app-content app-content-layout">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

the app-header contains just a basic md-toolbar view with a button that will toggle the sidebar

```
<md-toolbar>
  <button class="app-icon-button-toggle" (click)="navToggle()">
    <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
  </button>
<md-toolbar>
```

and this is logic or the components of the app-header

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() toggleSideNav = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  navToggle() {
    this.toggleSideNav.emit(true);
  }
}
```

and then I try this

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<app-header (navToggle)="app-navigation.toggle()"></app-header>
```

of course it didn't work cause its stupid but I dont know what to do. this is the reference that I follow. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2936

so basically the `md-sidenav` is located to `app-navigation` component. I want to toggle the `md-sidenav` using the `app-header` component. I use the `@Output` and `EventEmitter` but its not working. Believe me I did everything to work with this stuff, I also use the Service approach.

//this is the shared.service

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
    public sidenav: any;

}
```

// and this is the app-header using `Service` approach for `components interactions`.

```
template: '<button class="app-icon-button-toggle" (click)="toggleNav()">
               <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
           </button>';

export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private SharedService: SharedService) {

  }
  toggleNav() {
    this.SharedService.sidenav.toggle();
  }
}
```

every time that I clicked the toggle button on `HeaderComponent` it 
promp an error `toggle is undefined` so I gave up the Service approach. I have tons of reference that I use but the only thing that I focused on is this. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2936. I work everything but no luck, please help me out. Thank you

PS I'm newbie to angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `md-sidenav` should be in the same component as the `md-sidenav-container`. You can load a component inside it.

```
<md-sidenav-container>

  <md-sidenav #sidenav>
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  </md-sidenav>

  <app-header (navToggle)="sidenav.toggle()></app-header>


  <div class="app-content app-content-layout">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Note the `#sidenav` syntax. This is a template variable, so we can access it in the markup from the `(navToggle)` event. What you were doing originally (`app-navigation.toggle()`) won't work because there is no variable in the component named `app-navigation`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution is work for me and is simple

### mediator.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MediatorService {

  // SideNav: Boolean = true;
  sideNav: any = false;
  sideNavUpdated = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {

  }

  getSideNavState() {
    return this.sideNavUpdated;
  }

  setSideNavState (state) {
    this.sideNav = state;
    this.sideNavUpdated.emit(this.sideNav);
  }

}
```

### header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MediatorService } from '../../../Services/mediator.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  sideNav: Boolean;

  constructor(
    private mediator: MediatorService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setSideNavState() {
    this.sideNav = !this.sideNav;
    this.mediator.setSideNavState(this.sideNav);
  }

}
```

### header.component.html

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
  <span>
     <button md-icon-button (click)="setSideNavState()">
       <md-icon  class="color-white" style="vertical-align: middle;">menu</md-icon>
     </button>
  </span>
</md-toolbar>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MediatorService } from '../../Services/mediator.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  sidenavState: any = false;

  constructor(
     private mediator: MediatorService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sidenavState = this.mediator.getSideNavState();
    console.log(this.sidenavState);

  }

}
```

### home.component.html

```
 <md-sidenav-container style="margin-top: 5px;">

   <md-sidenav mode="side" opened="{{sidenavState | async }}">

      <h1>Works</h1>

    </md-sidenav>

    <p>Yepppppppp</p>

 </md-sidenav-container>
```